# The Master node have to throuth http proxy connect Slave, How do I do?

Tags: jenkins

My jenkins master node be located in company local network. Have a jenkins slave Node in public cloud. The master node must be through HTTP PROXY to connect the slave node.
How do I configure master use a http proxy connect the slave node?
Thank's for you help!